# Unable to adjust the design when using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am trying to just show that you can send your message and not hardcode all the messages in my frontend. I made use of an already developed code by a guy here's the link https://codepen.io/FilipRastovic/pen/pXgqKK

I have added the id="msg" in the input field and id="chatpanel" where class is chat-panel

Image attached. Now, the issue is that the message gets send (just in the display)b but the bubble is placed below the input area[image: Now, the issue is that the message gets send (just in the display)b but the bubble is placed below the input area.]

Here's my additional JS code.

```
function send(){
    
var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
var div1=document.createElement("div");
div1.classList.add("row","no-gutters");

  
  var div2=document.createElement("div");

  div2.classList.add("col-md-3","offset-md-9");
  

    
  
  var div3=document.createElement("div");
  div3.classList.add("chat-bubble","chat-bubble--right");
  

var text=document.createTextNode(msg);
  
  div3.appendChild(text);
  div2.appendChild(div3);
  div1.appendChild(div2);
  
  var main=document.getElementById("chatpanel");
  
  main.appendChild(div1);


}
```

Comment: Looks like `#msg` is also a child of `#chatpanel` -> [`.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Comment: Yesss, I worked. Thankyou so muchh for helping me out.

Comment: You might want to add this as an answer and accept it to mark this question as "solved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the message input box is located in the `#chatpanel` div. When you append the new message to the `#chatpannel` div, it will get added after the last element in that div. You need to take the `#msg` input (and it's containing div) and move it out of the `#chatpannel` div.

Your code is roughly like this:

```
<div id="chatpannel">
    <div class="msg-box-container">
        <input type="text" id="msg" />
        <button type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you need to make it like this:

```
<div id="chatpannel">
</div>
<div class="msg-box-container">
    <input type="text" id="msg" />
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```